# How to redirect a System.Windows.Controls.TextBox input to a stream?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, stream, winforms

I tried:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    streamWriter.Write(e.Key.ToString());
}
```

But I don't know how to convert a Key to string correctly. I also tried:

```
private void textBox1_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    streamWriter.Write(e.Text);
}
```

But this event is not called. The farthest I went was:

```
private string previous = string.Empty;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = textBox1.Text.Substring(previous.Length);
    streamWriter.Write(text);
    previous = textBox1.Text;
}
```

But this has problems with character deletion, and many other cases.
What should I do?

Comment: On the TextBox you can handle PreviewTextInput rather than TextInput which "...may have already been handled by the internal implementation..." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to use `KeyPress` instead of `KeyDown`.

[KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx) provides the actual char, already translated appropriately.  Just write this char to your stream directly.

---

Edit:

After seeing in the comments that this is WPF, not Windows Forms (as tagged), the above will not exist.

That being said, I question your goal here - using a textbox to write to a stream, in a character by character fashion, is always going to be problematic.  This is due to what you wrote in your last sentence:

> But this has problems with character deletion, and many other cases.

Personally, I would take one of two different approaches:

1. Use a TextBox as a "buffer", and only send the entire contents to the stream when the focus is lost, etc.  This way, the user can delete, etc, as needed, and you always have a complete "string" to work with.  This would probably be my first choice, if you want the behavior to be similar to what you're after now.
2. Don't use a TextBox for this.  Use some other control which allows text entry, but not deletion or selection.  If you must use a TextBox, and must handle key-by-key streaming, then you should restrict the input (via a behavior or attached property) to only the character you wish, which means disabling deletion.

Comment: I can't find `KeyPress`. I'm using WPF.

Comment: I found only KeyDown and KeyUp.

Comment: @Jader Dias: Your question is tagged windows-forms, so I was assuming Windows Forms, not WPF...

Comment: do you know the solution for WPF?

Comment: @Jader Dias: Edited my answer with suggestions.

Comment: @Reed I created also a Windows Forms project, to test the Keypress